# System state design composition

Tags: java, object-oriented-design, state

Consider the following Java code:

```
public class HumanStateImpl implements HumanState {
    private boolean alive;
    private Color skinColor;

    // getters and setters, other state fields

    @Override
    public boolean isAlive() {
        return alive;
    }
}
```

Now imagine I want to have a class that represents `HandState`, and a corresponding `HandController`. **Is it better to inject the state objects of each level of state separately, or compose them into one most-specific state object?** If it depends, what does it depend on?

To clarify what I mean, here is an implementation of both sides, respectively:

```
public class HandState {
    private final Side handSide;
    private boolean closed;
}

public class HandController {
    private final HumanState humanState;
    private final HandState handState;

    public HandController(HumanState humanState, HandState handState) {
        this.humanState = humanState;
        this.handState = handState;
    }
}
```

Versus:

```
public class HandState implements HumanState {
    private final HumanState outerState;
    private final Side handSide;

    public HandState(HumanState outerState, Side handSide) {
        this.outerState = outerState;
        this.handSide = handSide;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAlive() {
        return outerState.isAlive();
    }
}

public class HandController {
    private final HandState handState;

    public HandController(HandState handState) {
        this.handState = handState;
    }
}
```

Comment: So ... every `Hand` is a `Human` and therefore ... has a `Mouth`?

Comment: @rwong - it's an admittedly strained analogy. The OP doesn't wish to / can't reveal the true scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** - I think you're going to want to inject state objects at each level of state as appropriate.

Reason being, as your application scales and you add in more controllers you're going to want to control which controllers talk with which other ones.  And the first approach you suggested will position you better to support that.

---

To help illustrate things, let's draw out your example quite a bit further.

We've got a `Human` who has decided to go shopping (aka "gone to market"). To make things fun, we're going to go to one of those super-crazy, open market bazaars where savvy folk can participate in both buying *and* selling as they stroll along.

While at the market, the `Eyes` are taking in all the items available for purchase or consumption.  They're constantly scouting out deals - any situation where you might be able to buy or sell and make some money.

The `Brain` is keeping track of the prices that it sees as well as any goods that have been purchased so far.

The `Brain` is smart enough that it knows it has to offload some of its work.  So it relies on the `Wrists` in order to determine if a particular deal is good or not.

But even the `Wrists` know that they've got too much to do, so they rely upon the `Fingers` to determine how much should be picked up or offered for sale.  In stock market parlance, this would be akin to determining the spread.

Finally, we'll need some sort of `Basket` to carry the inventory.

---

A sample data flow might be:

```
Eyes --> Brain <--> Wrists <--> Fingers       Basket
```

In other domains, we may want a non-linear graph, but I think that in this case you don't.  With just 5 elements, we have a huge number of communication paths *if* every component can talk with every other component.

Part of what makes this model manageable is when you cut down on those numbers of interactions.  For example, the `Eyes` shouldn't really know what's in the `Basket` and absolutely shouldn't be responsible for making buy or sell decisions.  It's the same reasoning behind the colloquialism "your eyes were bigger than your stomach" when someone is super hungry and has a meal.

And note that the `Basket` is off by itself.  The `Brain` may need to ask the `Basket` to see if an item is in there or to see how much money is available<sup>1</sup>.  Likewise, the `Fingers` may need to access the `Basket` to place or remove items into the `Basket`'s inventory.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If the `Basket` shouldn't know how much money is available, then just create a `Wallet` or similar object.</sub>

---

Getting back to state injection...

The `Brain` will need to inject some measure of state into the `Wrists`.  The `Brain` needs to say what it thinks the current market price is and potentially what's already in the basket.  The `Wrists` can assume that if the `Brain` called them that the market is open.

But the `Brain` shouldn't be talking directly to the `Fingers` since they really don't talk about the same things.  The `Fingers` are there to determine how much to pick up or place down based upon what the `Wrists` told them.  If the `Fingers` need additional approval before finalizing the decision, then the approval should be routed to the `Wrists` and then back to the `Brain`.

By controlling which objects talk to the others, you limit the amount of state that has to be injected throughout your model.

If you look at the alternative that you suggested, having a single state object could easily get out of hand quite quickly.  And it muddies the waters since you're injecting or exposing states to controllers that simply don't care about those particular states.  For example, the `Fingers` don't care if the market is open, they just figure out how much to pick up.

Likewise, let's really extend your example and say that you're modeling a human with multiple arms so multiple (buy | sell) decisions can be made at the same time.  Think of how large a single state controller would have to expand out into while keeping track of 10 sets of `Wrists` and 10 more sets of `Fingers`.

*So to summarize all of that up:* You want to inject state objects at each level of state as appropriate, which means that you also limit which controllers can talk with which other controllers.

Comment: While I do agree with your general argument, complex systems will surely exhibit more subtle relationships between objects. Nature indeed decided to wire our brain directly to our fingers. Yes, this is an anti-pattern as our brain is a god object, but it works pretty well :)

Comment: @Tibo - I certainly agree that the analogy gets strained at points.  Using separate cortexes within the brain would fit better, but probably wouldn't be as clear to follow.  And then I would get into endless sniping about the involvements of the hippocampus vs. the frontal lobes vs. the motor cortex vs. the ... :-P

Comment: @GlenH7 Just got back from being out of town. So having a `Finger` constructor with lots of state objects is an acceptable "evil"?

Comment: @durron597 - if I'm envisioning `Finger` correctly, it shouldn't have "lots of state objects" but I could see where it would have more than others.  In my simplistic model, it would probably just see its `Wrist` and the `Basket`.  Single Responsibility Principle ought to help scope the amount of state that has to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using composition instead of inheritance in this scenario. Also, I would reverse the model to match the logical flow of control.

A `HumanState` can contain member variables for the `HandState`s. In this way, you have a logical composition of elements.

```
HumanState ->
--> contains HandState x2
--> contains HeadState x1
    --> contains MouthState x1
```

and so on.

Now the controllers can also follow the same pattern. The `HumanController` contains instances of `HandController`s. This pattern also matches intuitive assumptions - a human controls their hands, etc.

```
HumanController ->
--> contains HandController x2
--> contains HeadController x1
    --> contains MouthController x1
```

Comment: If the `Controller` need to play the role of mediating all sorts of communications between different body parts, maybe it is more aptly named `BodyPartsController`, and thus there is one such instance per person. If `Controller` refers to a part-specific GUI, then it is correct to have one such for each type of body parts.

Comment: @rwong I agree.. it would be good to differentiate between those use cases. But I would probably call the first case a `BodyPartsManager` or `BodyPartsCollaborator`, not `Controller`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm initially unclear on the meaning of `Controller`.